# What is the best mission to gain lots of money in gta v online below rank 3

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

If your rank is below 30, what would be the best mission in *GTA V Online* to farm money?

Comment: Can't believe they made so many Greater Toronto Area games

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Rooftop Rumble - Rank 75 - $18,500 Cash, 3950 RP
- Survival - Lowest Rank 15 - $30,000 Cash, Tons of RP

Answer (score 0):

Racing will bring you around 800-1200 a minute. Missions like Coveted you can bring up in your job menu. Coveted pays 18000 I think. Doing missions for your rank(not higher) for the first time will give you double cash. So doing every mission without buying ammo should give you an intake of about 300-1500 a minute.

Comment: So do about 3 races. Then missions will start being sent to you. I play Hardcore so if my second character dies... deleted. This week I've done it about 15 times.

Comment: Sell a car too. Every 48 minutes, between mission.